# What are these controls called?

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, user-controls

I'm trying to find a text box control, implemented in Javascript/CSS, where a user enters text, then when they press enter the text is converted into an interior element which can be removed (example below):

[image: Mystery textbox thingy]

I've found a few examples, including [this](http://blog.pixelingene.com/2010/10/tokenizing-control-convert-text-to-tokens/) and [this](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) and the tags box on SO (but I don't need autocomplete functionality - it should accept any text) and I know I could make one if I needed to, but what I'm really after is the *name* of these controls.

Is there even an agreed name for these things? Something like 'tagbox' or 'tokenbox' or something? They're everywhere, surely there are plenty of libraries, plugins etc which offer this style of input control.

Comment: No agreed name, but when I needed one I searched for "tagging autocompleter" and similar things which brought most of them up.

Comment: @JaredFarrish No, not in JIRA. Not sure what that is.

Comment: JIRA uses something really similar (create an account here and try to create an issue: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/TST). They call it a **label picker**, but as @Dave suggested, it could be called a `tag autocomplete`, `tag autosuggest`, or some other name. Just depends.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen it called a token field, both in Cocoa ([NSTokenField](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTokenField_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) and in a jQuery plugin ([tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)).